# WriteFile behaviour different when program is launched by VS

Tags: c++, winapi, console, visual-studio-2013

I am attempting to write UTF8 strings to stdout - and have them correctly displayed in the console.

To achieve this I am using `SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8)` and writing the data with `WriteFile`. The result is as expected, my string is displayed properly. The problem arises only when checking how many bytes are actually written: When called from a normal command console, it will properly count the number of bytes, regardless whether stdout is redirected or not. When started from VS2013, it reports the number of *characters* written instead.

Obviously, not knowing how many bytes actually got written make this approach borderline useless.

What I would like to know:

- Is there any reasonable explanation for this? It seems as this should be a bug?
- Is there a simple fix/workaround that I can use here?

A short example program that displays the described behavior:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int wmain(int, wchar_t const**)
{
    UINT oldcp = GetConsoleOutputCP();
    if (!SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "setting cp failed\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    unsigned char utf8data[] = { 'H', 0xc3, 0xa4, 'l', 'l', 0xc3, 0xb6, '!', '\n', 0x00 };
    DWORD size = (DWORD)(sizeof(utf8data) / sizeof(*utf8data)) - 1;

    fprintf(stderr, "bytes in data: %d\n", size);
    DWORD written = 0;
    BOOL success = WriteFile(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), utf8data, size, &written, nullptr);
    if (!success) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "WriteFile failed\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "bytes written: %d\n", written);

    SetConsoleOutputCP(oldcp);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output when called as `consoleutf8.exe`:

```
bytes in data: 9
Hällö!
bytes written: 9
```

Output when called as `consoleutf8.exe > out.txt` (`out.txt` contains the correct 9 bytes):

```
bytes in data: 9
bytes written: 9
```

Output when called from VS (ctrl+f5 or f5 does not matter, Debug/Release neither):

```
bytes in data: 9
Hällö!
bytes written: 7
```

P.S.: I am aware that I can detect if a console is attached and then use `WriteConsoleW` on an UCS2-encoded version of my data, however I would like to circumvent this if possible.

Comment: A classic solution for issues between launch with and without Visual Studio is to initialize all variables.  Some IDEs and sometimes compiling under Debug, will initialize the variables to zero; but release won't.

Comment: I do not see any uninitialized variables in my code. Maybe you could point out where exactly you see cause for further initialization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is the console settings. The default VS debug console uses raster fonts which don't render your text properly. You probably have your personal consoles set to use Lucida, which renders the text fine and returns 7 bytes written. If you change the VS console to use the same you get the same result.

Comment: I can repro what @HerrJoebob says - when my cmd console is set to raster fonts, I get `bytes written: 9` and the output is gibberish.  If I change the console font to Consolas or Lucida console, I get `bytes written: 7` and a readable word.  However, I would think that `WriteFile()` should return the number of bytes it passed to the device, not the number of bytes the device 'cooked' that data into for display purposes, right? Seems to me that this should be considered a bug in `WriteFile()`.

Comment: This indeed seems to be the problem. And to be honest is beyond ridiculous, I never expected the font of the console to impact WriteFile...

Comment: Agree with both of you, hopefully somebody with more internals knowledge will comment on why this is.